# OpenVPN(VPN) и DNS - шифруется или нет?

Tags: dns, openvpn

Какие "дыры" или потенциальные опастности имеет OpenVPN?

Случайно натыкаюсь на https://events.yandex.ru/lib/talks/2326/ - 1:06:46 там вопрос про OpenVPN(VPN) и ответ на 1-2 минуты.
Не очень понял, поясните кто знает ...

Как понял я - что если мы настраиваем OpenVPN  как шлюз в интернет, то все идет через ДНС провайдера и не шифруется верно?

А вот, если я настраиваю OpenVPN без выхода в сеть, для доступа к внутренним ресурсам, доступных только внутри ВПН сети, то тоже получается, что не шифрованный трафик пойдет через ДНС провайдера?

Раньше не задумывался, а тут, чтот задумался  или еще хуже запутался)

Разъясниете пожалуйста или где почтать можно про это?

Comment: В случае без выхода в сеть, естественно куда вы обращаетесь вне ВПН то будет не шифровано, т.к. будет использоваться другой сетевой интерфейс для доступа к запрашиваемому ресурсу, а внутри сети будет шифроваться. Или я не понял вопрос ?

Comment: ну да ... если я подключаюсь к ВПН серверу и пользуюсь его сервисами и прочим. то трафик по любому шифруется? точ то трафик вне ВПн - это понятно . что он не шифруется ... меня смущает и не понимает вопрос о ДНС. весь я подключаюсь и пробрасываю туннель через ДНС провайдера , но вот запросы я шлю внутрь ВПН, и они ... все .. поплыл я )  а как проверить можно, что запрос прошел через/в тунель или нет? сниферить? или анализатором трафика? из вне получается надо слушать. имитация  вламывания себя...

Answer (score 3):

DNS - это обычный протокол на основе UDP. Соответственно, пойдет он через VPN или нет, определяется по общим правилам роутинга, точно таким же, как и для остального траффика.

Есть всего два варианта:

1. DNS сервер у вас в той сети, доступ к которой осуществляется через VPN (например, у вас "интернет через VPN" и прописан гугловский DNS) - DNS траффик пойдет через VPN.
2. DNS сервер у вас в сети, доступ к которой осуществляется не через VPN (например, у вас прописан DNS провайдера при прямом к нему подключении. или в качестве DNS прописан adsl-модем). Тогда траффик пойдет в обход VPN.

проверить, через что именно в конкретном случае уходит DNS-траффик, можно вызовом `tracert <ip вашего dns-сервера>`

Comment: точно ... tracert...

Comment: то есть traceroute 10.8.0.1
traceroute to 10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  10.8.0.1 (10.8.0.1)  1.217 ms !X  1.667 ms !X  1.672 ms !X
это исчерпывающая информация? то есть весь трафик на правленный на 10.8.0.1 идет как надо (Это ВПН для доступа к своим ресурсам )?

Comment: @Трезвый сделайте трейс до вашего dns сервера, а не до vpn сервера. его адрес есть в выводе `ipconfig /all`

Comment: ааа, что бы посмотреть не идет ли на днс трафик через впн?) посмотрю...

Answer (score 0):

Все что внутри шифруется, ну так если у тебя внутри происходит работа, тоесть грубо говоря твой ресурс 10.8.0.1 как ты к нему доступ получишь из вне ?? тоесть тебе полюбе идти через виртуальный интерфейс TAP или TUN , а он на своем уровне шифрует, т.к его организовывает как раз таки openVPN(а в ней OpenSSL), и не шифрованные данные сервер не примет.

Comment: Значит верно все понял...